# How to explode 1 column from mysql using php when you are selecting multiple columns and putting a representation for every exploded data?

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to explode when im selecting only 1 column, but im selecting multiple column and 1 of them is i need to explode.

here is my php code:

```
$id="2010104404";

$json_output = array();

$dbc = mysqli_connect($mysql_servername, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_dbname) or die('Error connecting to MySql server'); 
$sql = "SELECT course_id, sections_id, rooms_id, sections_id, start_time, end_time, day from schedule_tbl where professor_id='$id' GROUP BY course_id, sections_id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json_output[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($json_output);
```

I want to explode the "day" column and represent the data exploded as:1-sunday, 2-monday, 3-tuesday and so on then echo it.
In my database it displays like this:
[image: my database table]

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `explode('-', $row['day'])`? That will output a PHP array similar to this: `[0 => 2, 1 => 4, 2 => 6]` based on the second row of your table. Then you can use that as you please. Do you also need help to add the day names?

Comment: oh okay now i get what you are saying about this: explode('-', $row['day']) dumb me like this right:

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $e[] = explode(" ", $row['day']);
            foreach($e as $r) {
                echo $r;
            }
        }

yep i need help for the day names, if you're not that busy sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the day names' array be:

```
$weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']; // 0-6
```

Now do this (NOTE: This can be modified to use Strings rather than arrays or whatever you may need, but it's one possible way):

```
$id="2010104404";
$json_output = [];
$dbc = mysqli_connect($mysql_servername, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_dbname) or die('Error connecting to MySql server'); 
$sql = "SELECT course_id, sections_id, rooms_id, sections_id, start_time, end_time, day from schedule_tbl where professor_id='$id' GROUP BY course_id, sections_id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $days = explode('-', $row['day']);
    $text = [];
    foreach($days as $day){ // day will be 1-7, so we will subtract 1
        $day = intval($day); // for the $weekdays index, primarily
        $text[] = $day.'-'.$weekdays[$day-1];
    }
    // $text will be something like this: [0 => '2-Monday', 1 => '4-Wednesday', 2 => '6-Friday']
    $json_output[] = $text; // $json_output will group like [0 => $text, 1 => $text, ...], $text being whatever happened on each loop (different every time).
}
echo json_encode($json_output);
```

### EDIT

To include all other selections into your `$json_output`, you need to do just as I did with `$text`. Something like this:

```
$json_output[] = $row['course_id'];
$json_output[] = $row['sections_id'];
$json_output[] = $row['rooms_id'];
$json_output[] = $row['start_time'];
$json_output[] = $row['end_time'];
$json_output[] = $text;
```

About the days outputting in a weird way... what values have you used? The same as in your database picture? I just used an example...

### EDIT 2

If you want to keep all other values with the same index, then add `$v = 0` **before** the while loop, then do `$v++;` **before closing the while loop**, and finally do `$json_output[$v]` on every assignment.

### EDIT 3

To remove the brackets from the final JSON String, let the values be Strings rather than arrays containing Strings. Like this:

> *If there are many days in a row*, this will require some **further editing**.

```
    $text = '';
    foreach($days as $day){ // day will be 1-7, so we will subtract 1
        $day = intval($day); // for the $weekdays index, primarily
        $text .= $day.'-'.$weekdays[$day-1];
    }
```

Comment: hmm sir zeke its output is lke this: [["7-Saturday"],["4-Wednesday"],["2-Monday"],["2-Monday"]]. The course_id,sections_id, rooms_id,start_time, and end_time is not being included, How to include it in my json output? BUT THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR ANSWER. I will also find a way for my another prob

Comment: same as the database picture sir! well thank you sir for your answer :)

Comment: wait sir how do i remove the bracket?

Comment: What bracket are you talking about?

Comment: its output is like this: ["IT173P","A58","R205","07:00:00","11:30:00",["7-Saturday"],"IT178P","B58","R212","11:30:00","16:00:00",["4-Wednesday"],"IT179P","A56","R205","07:00:00","10:00:00",["2-Monday"],"IT179P","A58","R214","11:30:00","16:00:00",["2-Monday"]]

--how do i temove the bracket in: ["2-Monday"] and ,["4-Wednesday"] And ["7-Saturday"]?

Comment: As for the days... I just supposed it was 1-7 (Sun-Sat), if you're saving the values from 0-6 (Sun-Sat), then simply do not subtract 1 from the index in here: `$weekdays[$day-1]`... so instead do `$weekdays[$day]`. That is an important thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Oh, I see... in that case don't use `$text[]`. I'll update my answer to show you how.

Comment: hmm it's sun to sat sir your code is correct for subtracting i just want to remove the bracket :) but i think i can get the data even with bracket

Comment: You're welcome. I'm very intrigued about a few things, but I'll keep helping as much as I can. But I'm getting off now, so if there are any more questions, I'll answer whenever I get back. Good luck.

Comment: thank you sir i don't have questions anymore. Thank you!!